# basic http auth in Clojure/Friend

Tags: clojure, basic-authentication, compojure

I am trying to make a basic auth for an API in Clojure with [friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend-demo/blob/master/src/clj/cemerick/friend_demo/http_basic.clj).

Here is the login request :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'user=myuser%40email.com&pass=super-secret-password' http://localhost:3000/login/
```

I am using compojure as well, but I'm not sure how to reuse the linked example. Here are the parts that I don't know how to change :

- How do I replace the username/password fields with user/pass fields like in my curl request ? I am able to extract them from the raw request, but I don't know how to pass it to Friend (do I need to change the `credential-fn`?).
- Replace the [user atom](https://github.com/cemerick/friend-demo/blob/master/src/clj/cemerick/friend_demo/users.clj) with data from the database. I have a `auth [email password]` that returns true or false (fetching from the database and using bcrypt). I can also fetch the user role from the database. How do I use the database (specifically I use mongo/monger) instead of the user atom ?

Comment: Your second part about replacing the user atom would probably be better in its own question.

Comment: @DanielCompton I already have a function that fetches data from the database, so my only concern is about Friend I guess. Don't you agree ?

Comment: You might find helpful this little skeleton I shared to integrate friend on Liberator where I used an in-memory mock user DB. https://github.com/jaimeagudo/liberator-friend. Don't miss the [post](https://sritchie.github.io/2014/01/17/api-authentication-with-liberator-and-friend/) :)

Comment: @JamesSharp Thanks I'm having a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a totally different *credential-fn*, or stick to the demo where *credential-fn* is implemented using *cemerick.friend.credentials/bcrypt-credential-fn*. Read the doc of *bcrypt-credential-fn* at https://github.com/cemerick/friend/blob/master/src/cemerick/friend/credentials.clj, it is quite long. It expects a *load-credentials-fn* that loads a user given a username string, then checks if the password matches. In the demo, the *load-credentials-fn* is a map in the users atom, but if you have a database you would want to provide a different load-credentials-fn function that would lookup the database, you don't want to load your users table in the map in the atom.

Comment: thank you. So if I make a custom function that returns a map, what should be inside the map ?

Comment: The result of this function is the authentication object, i.e. what cemerick.firend/current-authentication will return if you call it from the app (to render a greeting with user name, for example), e.g.: {:name "John" :roles #{:admin :user} :shoe-size 42}. Not sure if there aren't some details about the roles that I miss here.